# How to exclude specific folders when using dd command to backup sd card to an external SSD?

Tags: backup, sd-card, dd

I have linux formatted SSD connected to my raspberry pi, I want to backup my sd card using dd command,

`sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=os_image_from_sdcard.img`

I tried to use this https://github.com/lzkelley/bkup_rpimage , but it does not work

and this https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone.git is overly complicated

Comment: Seems it's not possible: https://askubuntu.com/questions/922624/how-to-exclude-path-from-dd-command